# Where to install Grub for Debian install?

Tags: boot, debian, bootloader, usb-storage, persistent

[image]

should i install grub on sdb or sda ??
(im installing debian on 32GB , the USB has  UEFI)

Answer (score 1):

The GRUB bootloader needs to be on whatever disk your BIOS/UEFI boots from after the installation.

You are probably installing from the USB device - and you'll remove that, so pick the ATA device which is likely your internal hard drive (or emulated hard drive) - the 32GB device you were talking about.

Comment: a friend yesterday clicked on the second one (sdb)..
it worked fine, but i still don't get why i don't have a Graphical User Interface, i manually installed sudo and i m trying to install the gnome, i accidentally removed the usb and now im running dpkg --configue -a ..
i wish they made Debian easy install like Ubuntu

Comment: If you install GRUB on a removable drive, it'll boot your OS, until you turn your computer on without it connected.  Ask new, different questions by using the Ask Questions button - but check to see if someone answered it first. :)

Comment: i couldn't install debian .
i tried to install Debian files on a USB using diskparallel and iso images but everytime the installation crash i don't know why .
i don't wanna use a bootable usb .
what i want is either physically install debian on another mac partition or install it completely on USB .
i couldn't